# SQL Join query with aggregate function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a monthly table and daily table. I need to  compare the record count based on user ID, transaction submit date, total amount i.e.  for a transaction submit date and for a user id, I need to know the count of records and sum of total amount.

```
Transaction submit date     Cust Number Total amount
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       700           0.7
1/1/2017                       797           0
1/1/2017                       797           1.4
1/1/2017                       797           1.6
```

If I have table like this. Need to aggregate the total amount, based on transaction submit date and row count i.e.

```
1/1/2017     700   7      4.9
```

like wise do it for daily & monthly table and want results. 
So, that I know on particular transaction date, what's the row count for particular customer id in monthly and daily.
I am able to it separately for two tables export the results to excel and compare. But, wanted to know can we handle this in a single query.

Comment: So in the *monthly* table you also have *daily* records? Or how would you compare results for a *date*? I'd have expected you to ask for comparing the aggregated data per month instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT DATE
        ,Number
        ,Count(Total)
        ,SUM(Total)
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY DATE
        ,Number
```

Comment: I am having two tables. I need to compare the results. I understand the query can handle only a single table.

Comment: can you provide the schema of each table? It can be done using CTE

Comment: Table 1: order_table_Monthly 
Columns: Transaction_submit_date, Customer_number, Amount.

Table 2: order_table_Daily 
Columns: Transaction_submit_date, Customer_number, Amount.

Same records go into these tables. But as the name suggest,  one table updates daily. the other monthly. 

I have to compare both the tables on transaction submit date, customer number, then show the row count and total.

Answer (score 0):

Please try This, Crete Monthly and Daily CTES and join them, this will give equal records.

```
 With Montyly as
 (
 SELECT Montyly
      ,Number
    ,Count(Total) MCount
    ,SUM(Total) MTotal
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY DATE
    ,Number
 ),
With Daily as
(
SELECT DATE
    ,Number
    ,Count(Total) DCount
    ,SUM(Total) DTotal
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE
    ,Number
 )

select * from 
Montyly M inner join Daily D on
M.Date=D.Date and M.Number=D.Number and M.MCount=D.DCount and M.MTotal.D.DTotal
```

Comment: Hello,
I am trying to run the query as per your  inputs(as mentioned above).
But, There is an error which says,
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10"
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'With'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.